# view capturing in background

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

we can easily capture a view(screenshot) programmatically in iPhone.
But i am trying to capture screen automatically after every 5 seconds.that also, can be done.

But my main objective is , to capture screen, even if the app is closed, i.e in background.
Apple doesn't allow to background process to run for a long time, but can we do it for 5-10 min in background.

Capturing screen,even if the app is closed.Ofcourse user can close this function, within the app.

Apple might reject this, but is this possible ?
Regards

Comment: Can you explain how you capture the screen while your app is in the background? Everything I have found seems to rely on capturing the app's own UIView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible but it's not easy. You can register you app (via a .plist setting) as being a media app, this will allow it to run in the background. This is normally to allow media apps to continue playing music when the app is sent to the background. However if you are careful you can get it to do other thing in there too.

In your plist under "Required Background Modes" add a key "Item 0" and set it to "App plays Audio". This will mean you can do it.

You will then have to using AVAudioPlayer, play a silent sound that is say 5mins long, and then register one of your controllers for the AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification notification. Then when this calls back, you can have your bit of code that, first takes a screenshot, and then starts the sound again.

This is the general concept, look somewhere like :

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_background-audio/

for how to set up the audio playing.

Just a note: APPLE WILL REJECT THIS!

If you are making an app for personal use only, this is fine, but will never make it to the app store.

Hoep this sheds some light on your situation! :)